# Check if a file exists in the android resources - Android

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I am trying to get a video from `"android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/video"`, and it reads it perfectly. How can I check if that file exists or is missing?

Comment: give your file a name. Split the file name from the above path and match both strings.

Comment: But how can I check if the file exists? @SafanMomin

Comment: @FrankFabregat check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check like this .

```
int checkExistence = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION", "raw", mContext.getPackageName());

if ( checkExistence != 0 ) {  // the resouce exists...
result = true;
}
else {  // checkExistence == 0  // the resouce does NOT exist!!
result = false;
}
```

Comment: I will test this in a bit. Thanks

Comment: None of them are working. They are outputting everything as false

Comment: Yes, I have it like that, exactly as you put it in your first answer

Comment: what is the mContext for?

Comment: if you are calling this in activity then don't use mContext.if in fragment then get context from the activity.

Comment: `The last approach.? `. Very probable as the first two are big nonsense.